# mixing constant and variable column names in dplyr::mutate/transmute

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

I am trying to change the class of a dataframe column using dplyr. The name of the target column is contained in a variable

```
my_df<-data.frame(colour=c("red","blue","green"),
                  val1=as.character(c(1,12,13)),
                  val2=c(21,22,23))

target_var="val1"
```

After some fiddling I managed to reach my goal using standard R subsetting:

```
my_df %>% transmute(colour = colour,
                 !!myval := as.numeric(.[,myval]))
```

But I suspect that there are less complex ways of referring to the target column, which is more consistent with other 'dplyr' expressions. I have tried solving this question with the information from the ["Programming with dplyr"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) vignette, but no luck. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you found that a possible answer provided you with the solution you were looking for, please consider accepting it as the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use the `sym` to convert to `symbol` and then with `!!`

```
my_df %>%
    transmute(colour = colour, 
        !!target_var := as.numeric(as.character(!!rlang::sym(target_var))))
#    colour val1
#1    red    1
#2   blue   12
#3  green   13
```

NOTE: There the 'val1' is `factor` because by default `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`.  So, we need to convert it to `character` and then to `numeric`

#### data

```
my_df<-data.frame(colour=c("red","blue","green"),
              val1=as.character(c(1,12,13)),
              val2=c(21,22,23))

target_var <- "val1"
```

Comment: Thanks akrun -- this is what i've been looking for.  I've posted a slightly simpler version of your solution, that does not require rlang.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the `mutate_at` function. Your code would look like this then:

```
library(tidyverse) # to load dplyr and tibble

# I took the liberty to add val3 to show how you can do it with multiple variables
my_df <- data_frame(colour = c("red", "blue", "green"),
                    val1 = as.character(c(1, 12, 13)),
                    val2 = c(21, 22, 23),
                    val3 = as.character(c(1, 12, 13)))

# same here...
target_var <- c("val1", "val3")


my_df %>% 
  mutate_at(.funs = as.numeric, .vars = target_var)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   colour  val1  val2  val3
#>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    red     1    21     1
#> 2   blue    12    22    12
#> 3  green    13    23    13
```

The only drawback to this method is that you end up with the full dataset (`mutate`) and not with the selected variables (as you would with `transmutate`). You could use `transmutate_at`, but that applies the supplied function to all selected variables.

Comment: thanks! Although it doesn't directly answer my question it is certainly very useful for my current script!

Answer (score 1):

I've found how to do this with a minimum of conversions:

```
my_df<-data.frame(colour=c("red","blue","green"),
              val1=as.character(c(1,12,13)),
              val2=c(21,22,23))

target_var="val1"

my_df %>% transmute(colour = colour,
                 !!my_val := as.numeric(!!as.symbol(target_var)))
```

Comment: Be careful, you still use dplyr in this solution! (%>% and transmute, as well as !!)

Comment: You are right, I wrongly assumed that 'rlang' had to be loaded explicity.